Python Pandas Grouping data between two specific dates
I'm trying to group data from a dataframe considering a specific date range that repeats monthly.
2024-01-26 to 2024-02-25
2024-02-26 to 2024-03-25
2024-03-26 to 2024-04-25
2024-04-26 to 2024-05-25
repeatedly
For this, I'm using the Grouper function, but I can't handle a custom frequency, cause it only allows me to group data monthly.
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DATE', axis=0, **freq='ME'**))[['POB']].sum()
The case would be to group data between two specific dates and how to create a date range that contains fixed days and variable months.
star_date = '2024-X1-26'

end_date = '2024-X2-25'

so on...

Here's one approach:
import pandas as pd

N = 10

data = {
    'DATE': pd.date_range('2023-01-01', periods=N, freq='8d'),
    'POB': range(N)
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

start_date = df['DATE'].min()
end_date = df['DATE'].max() + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
group = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='MS') + 
                  pd.offsets.Day(24), 
                  name='END_DATE')

g = pd.merge_asof(df['DATE'], group, left_on='DATE', right_on='END_DATE', 
                  direction='forward')['END_DATE']

out = df.groupby(g)['POB'].sum()

Output:
END_DATE
2023-01-25     6
2023-02-25    15
2023-03-25    24
Name: POB, dtype: int64

Explanation / Intermediates
df

        DATE  POB
0 2023-01-01    0
1 2023-01-09    1
2 2023-01-17    2
3 2023-01-25    3
4 2023-02-02    4
5 2023-02-10    5
6 2023-02-18    6
7 2023-02-26    7
8 2023-03-06    8
9 2023-03-14    9


Get min / max for df['DATE'] and adjust max to begin of next month (using pd.offsets.MonthBegin).
Use inside pd.date_range with freq='MS' and add the correct offset to get the end date of each group (using pd.offsets.Day).
Turn into a named pd.Series and use inside pd.merge_asof to assign values in df['DATE'] to the appropriate buckets.

pd.merge_asof(df['DATE'], group, left_on='DATE', right_on='END_DATE', 
              direction='forward')

        DATE   END_DATE
0 2023-01-01 2023-01-25 < start group 1
1 2023-01-09 2023-01-25
2 2023-01-17 2023-01-25
3 2023-01-25 2023-01-25
4 2023-02-02 2023-02-25 < start group 2
5 2023-02-10 2023-02-25
6 2023-02-18 2023-02-25
7 2023-02-26 2023-03-25 < start group 3
8 2023-03-06 2023-03-25
9 2023-03-14 2023-03-25


Now, apply df.groupby + groupby.sum.


it works perfectly!! much appreciated!

You can identify the dates where day is 26 and use cumsum to create groups:
# example dataframe
np.random.seed(42)
dates = pd.date_range(start="2024-01-01", end="2024-06-30", freq="D")
values = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=len(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame({"DATE": dates, "POB": values})

# optional if your data has gaps: ensure all dates are present
full_range = pd.date_range(df["DATE"].min(), df["DATE"].max())
df = full_range.to_frame(name="DATE").merge(df, how="left")

# solution
out = df.groupby(df["DATE"].dt.day.eq(26).cumsum(), as_index=False).agg(
    **{"start": ("DATE", "min"), "end": ("DATE", "max"), "sum": ("POB", "sum")}
)

       start        end   sum
0 2024-01-01 2024-01-25  1238
1 2024-01-26 2024-02-25  1538
2 2024-02-26 2024-03-25  1357
3 2024-03-26 2024-04-25  1700
4 2024-04-26 2024-05-25  1327
5 2024-05-26 2024-06-25  1549
6 2024-06-26 2024-06-30   163


it works perfectly!! much appreciated!

The data can be something like
date        POB
some date   1
some date   2
some date   3
some date   3

we can create a df1 containing the dates
    star_date   end_date
0   2024-01-26  2024-02-26
1   2024-02-26  2024-03-26
2   2024-03-26  2024-04-26
3   2024-04-26  2024-05-26

convert all your dates to datetime, and then using cut:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df1['star_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['star_date'])
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['date'], df1['star_date'])).agg({'POB': sum})

Output:
date                       POB  
(2024-01-26, 2024-02-25]   x
(2024-02-26, 2024-03-25]   y
(2024-03-26, 2024-04-25]   z


You could create a new column that contains the end date of your date grouping, then group by that new column.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
date_range = pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', end='2024-06-30', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': date_range,
    'POB': np.random.rand(len(date_range)) * 100,
})

def custom_month_group(date):
    if date.day < 26:
        return pd.Timestamp(date.year, date.month, 25)
    else:
        next_month = date.replace(day=1) + pd.DateOffset(months=1)
        return pd.Timestamp(next_month.year, next_month.month, 25)

df['month_group'] = df['date'].apply(custom_month_group)

result = df.groupby('month_group').agg({
    'POB': 'sum'
}).reset_index()

print(result)


One option is to shift() the dates back 25 days, then resample().
Using df from @ouroboros1's answer:
df.set_index('DATE').shift(freq = '-25D').resample('M')['POB'].sum().rename(lambda x: x + pd.Timedelta('25D')).reset_index()

Output:
        DATE  POB
0 2023-01-25    6
1 2023-02-25   15
2 2023-03-25   24

